# Discounts applied based on cart total

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

Our client would like to run a promotion which would require a user to spend at least £30 in order to get a certain product for free.

We have setup a ‘codeless’ discount that has:

- the product that they get free in the `Product` field in conditions
- The `Purchase Total` set to 30 (although I think this means the total value of the above products)
- The `Base Discount` amount to be the same as the value of the product (3.99).

I had assumed, that provided the cart > 30 and that product was in their cart, the 3.99 would be automatically removed from the total. Now I’m guessing it’s not doing that because of the way the `Purchase Total` works.

If that is the case, does anyone know how I’d achieve the desired outcome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, purchase total is the total of items selected.

We will look to add a 'Total Order Price' condition in the future.

For now you would need to make your own custom discount adjuster to build special discount conditions.